# Changing windows 8 workgroup name has locked me out

Tags: windows-8, control-panel, workgroup

I was trying to set up a workgroup for a windows 8 machine and an xp machine. I changed the workgroup name of the xp machine and restarted. I then changed the workgroup name of the windows 8 machine workgroup to the same name. After a restart here's a list of the problems I've encountered so far:

Much of control panel will not work, it just hangs. Such as:
network and sharing center
User accounts
Add remove programs

Other problems that I've found so far are:
The system tray is not loading properly
no access to services.msc (won't open)
no access to regedit.exe (won't open)
Unable to open cmd with admin rights.

I'm at a loss as to what to do given most of the solutions I've read include altering things in regedit etc. Without access to any of these my hands are tied.

Comment: System Restore? Can you start in Safe Mode?

Comment: Have you restarted the PC several times yet?